# Series identification late 90 early 2000's

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime, cartoon

I am looking for a cartoon/anime series.

Its a post-apocalyptic world and 3 guys travel with the last human. One of the guys, who is more of a boy, can transform into a man with a red hawk/eagle armor. One of the other guys can do things with water.

At some point the 3 transform together with a special sword in 1 guy to beat the big enemy

Comment: Anything else you can remember such as the country, language, network, episode length, time slot?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUe5Ugg6Iks

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154139/anime-boy-with-a-gem-on-his-forehead-could-transform-and-combine-as-could-a-c/

Answer (score 4):

**Could this be *[Shinzo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinzo)* (AKA *Mushrambo*)?**

The protagonist is described as the last human, he has three adult protectors helping him to cross a post-apocalyptic wasteland, one of the characters turns into a sort of hawk-dude with red armour, another has water skills.