# Anime: main character has a gem in his head, in which an old man resides later on, who can use blood magic

Tags: story-identification, anime

The main character of this anime has a gem in his head, in which an old man resides later on, who can use blood magic.

Additionally, he learns how to forge magic weapons and touches pillars which are stopping demons from entering their world. He is in love with girl who's a half-human, half-demon who gets controlled a lot.

The anime looks as if it is based in old Japan.

I watched it half a year ago and it starts of with the main character fighting monsters. It has about 20 or more episodes and when you get to the end part of the series he goes to a special island to do something and gets an artifact called the blood slate.

Comment: Can you give any more details about the anime? How many years ago you watched it, how many episodes it was, etc?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154139/anime-boy-with-a-gem-on-his-forehead-could-transform-and-combine-as-could-a-c is a superficial match.

Answer (score 3):

I found out what it was called.

*[Spiritual Domain](https://myanimelist.net/anime/36291/Ling_Yu)*, also called *Spirit Realm* or *Spirit Field* is an adaptation of the Chinese novel, *Ling Yu*.

> In the world of Ling Yu(Spiritual Field), there is a continent named Chilan(Red Tide), where warriors and their Spirit Weapons are classified into different levels. Families and clans follow a strict hierarchy, too. Under the leadership of the Xuantian Union, human warriors and the Evil Clan have been engaged in brutal fights on Nether Battlefield for hundreds of years. A Soul-devouring Beast sneaked into the Chilan Continent through a crevice on the Nether Battlefield before it ruthlessly slaughtered the Feng Town and the Gao Town. Qin Lie, a young man from the Ling Town, together with Ling Yushi and Gao Yu whom he had grown up with, was commanded to help the Xuantian Union in the conquest of the Soul-devouring Beast. He did not anticipate that he would be swallowed into a great conspiracy. To protect his friends and to rescue the one he loves, the powers hiding in his veins are awakening.

### Opening Theme

Comment: It looks like you accidentally created a new account. You can follow the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts to merge them so that you will be able to accept your self-answer. :)